# How to load strings and rc_data from a resource file in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

I have created successfully a resource file (.res) including some bitmaps, strings and a rc_data.
The linker doesn't give me errors.
I have found a way to load Bitmaps with success. 
Example:

Image1->Picture->Bitmap->LoadFromResourceName((unsigned int)HInstance, L"IMAGE91");

Where can I found a good example about strings and rc_data instead?
Please, remember, I am using C++ Builder.

Answer (score 0):

For resource strings, the AnsiString and UnicodeString classes have various LoadStr() and LoadString() methods.

For RCDATA, you can use TResourceStream (which is what TBitmap::LoadFromResource...() uses internally).